# Write entire HttpWebRequest to a file

Tags: c#, httprequest

```cs
byte[] jData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DATA);

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((sender, certificate, chain, policyErrors) => { return true; });

//required this (header method not working)
CredentialCache crCache = new CredentialCache();
crCache.Add(new Uri(URL), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(uName, uPwd));
req.Credentials = crCache;

//required below, to enable cookies to carry authentication value over each request.
req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

req.Accept = "application/json";
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
req.Headers.Add(headerKey, headerValue);

req.GetRequestStream().Write(jData, 0, jData.Length);

using (HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse()) {
    using (StreamReader strm = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream())) {
        result = strm.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

The above lines of code is a simple call to JSon Web service. The issue is the call is failing after sometime with UnAuthorized error. So I need to log HttpWeRequest to a text file to see the entire request. This should include headers, authentication credentials and body.. Can I know how can the entire request be captured and written to a file.

Thanks

Comment: First, you can reduce all this code to just 3-4 lines with HttpClient. Second, you can capture requests and responses easily using a debugging proxy like Fiddler.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @kanavos, the need is to log the request within the .NET framework. Cannot use wireshark or Fiddler

Comment: You can [enable network tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing) but that's a bit verbose. Or you can create and [use a logging HttpHandler with HttpClient](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-asp-net-core-logging). Which you should be using anyway. In fact, if you're in .NET Core 3+ you're already using it indirectly, as HttpWebRequest was reimplemented as a legacy wrapper on top of HttpClient

Comment: The answers to the duplicate describe both techniques - a logging HttpClientHandler and enabling network tracing

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < req.Headers.Count; ++i)
{
    string header = req.Headers.GetKey(i);
    foreach (string value in req.Headers.GetValues(i))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", header, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, this partly works and gives the header information. Wanted to know if we can recreate the entire request as is that's sent to clint.

Answer (score 1):

`GetResponseStream()` gives a stream of the response body no the whole response

You can use `Header` property of `HttpWebResponse` to catch headers

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse.headers?view=net-5.0#System_Net_HttpWebResponse_Headers